# Use LIKE with multiple names from a different table in UPDATE

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I'm looking to update a field to a different value if the string in `name` contains a value from a different table in PostgreSQL:

Table **Types** that needs to be updated

```
id  |  name          |  type
1   |  Google Page   |  WEBSITE
2   |  Yahoo Page    |  WEBSITE
3   |  Facebook Page |  WEBSITE
...
```

Table **Companies** that has the names

```
id  |  name    
1   |  Google
2   |  Yahoo
3   |  Facebook
4   |  Twitter
5   |  Stackoverflow
...
```

What I tried

```
UPDATE types
SET type = 'BUSINESS'
WHERE name LIKE CONCAT((SELECT companies.name from companies), '% Page')
```

But I'm getting this issue: `[21000] ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a subquery with exists logic to retain your current logic:

```
UPDATE types t
SET type = 'BUSINESS'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM companies c
              WHERE CONCAT(c.name, ' Page') = t.name);
```

You could also use an update join:

```
UPDATE types t
SET type = 'BUSINESS'
FROM companies c
WHERE t.name = CONCAT(c.name, ' Page');
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the IN directive:

```
WHERE name IN (SELECT CONCAT(companies.name, ' Page') name from companies)
```

Comment: Thank you man, your answer is very similar to what Tim posted, but I am still grateful for that

Answer (score 1):

Much cheaper than comparing concatenated strings:

```sql
UPDATE types t
SET    type = 'BUSINESS'
FROM   companies c
WHERE  right(t.name, 5) = ' Page'
AND    left(t.name, -5) = c.name;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7826ceeced04d85304fa5eb88f4c7801)*